# Unity clone won't appear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and i'm trying to spawn a clone of a ball in unity, but it won't appear.
It does spawn at the spawn point but it doesn't appear.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ball;
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnBall();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void SpawnBall()
    {
        Instantiate(ball, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Edit: it's a 3d game and the mesh renderer is enabled.

Comment: Is it a 2D game? Does the spawned gameobject has the component 'Sprite Renderer'? Is it a 3D game? Are you sure the mesh renderer isn't disabled?

Comment: it's a 3d game and the mesh renderer isn't disabled. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind: i just redid the ball and it worked.

¯_(ツ)_/¯